# Create symbolic function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do this: `syms f(x, y)`  but it is not working and throws the error: Not a valid variable name. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
syms x y;
f = sym('3*x + 4*y');
subs(f, {x,y}, {4,5}); % returns 32
```

Btw, quite a nice page on symbolic maths in MATLAB [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/symbolic_math.html)

Comment: actually, this is what I am trying to accomplish: dsolve(diff(y) == a*y, y(0) == b)  when I submit this expression I get: "??? Error using ==> sym.sym>checkindex at 2729
Index must be a positive integer or logical." Any idea on how to use it?

Comment: Well that should have been your question then! I'll have a look.

Comment: it's misleading because that is an example shown on Matlab's website and it's not working for me. I have Matlab 2011.

Comment: Yeah, the example doesn't work for me either. I'm not really sure what that snippet of code in your first comment is doing. You should update  your original question with all the relevant code.

Comment: this is the example and the code I need to solve my problem: "Solve this ordinary differential equation with the initial condition y(0) = b:

syms a b y(t)
dsolve(diff(y) == a*y, y(0) == b)" with all the right spaces

Comment: just to understand, I'm trying to get the exact solutions of a differential equation to compare them with the results obtained using Runge Kutta.

Answer (score 1):

It looks valid since it is the same as an example in http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/symbolic/syms.html. You could check `which x`, `which y` and `which f` to make sure that x, y and f aren't existing functions (I don't think symbolic variables can have the same name as a function)

You could also try:

```
x = sym('x');
y = sym('y');
f(x, y) = sym('f(x, y)');
```

This should do the same as your original code, but I don't see why it would work if `syms` doesn't.

Comment: when I type the last expression I get: "??? Error using ==> mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double
array.

If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead."